# window.print() crashes page in Chrome Version 114.0.5735.133 (Official Build) (arm64)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, window

I am trying to print the current page in Vue component using the below methods, but it crashes the entire page, as shown in the screenshot below. Currently my Chrome Version is `114.0.5735.133` (Official Build) (arm64), but previously it was working fine. Can anyone please help me out to fix this issue?

```
loadRecord(promises){
Promise.all([...promises]).then(() => {
   this.loading = false
   setTimeout(() => {
          this.print()
        }, 1000)
   })
},
print(){
   this.$nextTick(() => {  
        window.print() 
   })
},
```

[image: Screenshot of the page crash when trying to print the page using JavaScript code]